# Android location service in simulator

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am using the location service in android's simulator,

```
       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

but I am getting null on provider and location in simulator and this causing my app to crash.
Can I debug my program in simulator or I need to use a real phone?

Comment: if you paste your complete code we could help better to find your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this complete example about location http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/42.html

You don't need to use a real phone, emulator lets simulate that you get coordinates. You have to open DDMS perspective and in left hand you will find Emulator Control. In emulator control there is a panel for locations control, where you can introduce coordinates and send to the emulator

Comment: yes, I did but what good is emulator panel for submitting coordinate points manually when the error is java.langIllegalArgumentException provider=null, basically it needs a valid provider.